# Using a meanJS application (running grunt in the Linux terminal), how can I possibly implement and use NgReactGrid?

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

Has anyone been successful at using NgReactGrid to build table? I am pretty sure that I have to use npm install in the command line to get ngReactGrid (`npm install ngReactGrid --save`). I did that, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone please give me a steps by steps process on how to get this to work using the meanJS application framework?

At first, I was following the link below, but it hasn't been helpful enough. They are not using the meanJS application framework in that link, and I believe this is the reason why they have so many `<script>` statement in their source code.

I followed that link to try to understand what to do:
http://josebalius.github.io/ngReactGrid/

However, this is not what I really needs. For example, after executing `npm install ngReactGrid --save`. I am not sure how to actually use it to build a table. Maybe I install it wrong as well. Can anyone provide some steps by steps instructions on how to create a basic table.

I am not sure what to try do at this point. I am new to meanJS, and this is a pain to me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well generically after running npm install module --save, the module will be in your npm_modules directory. There it should contain all the required files you'll need to make it work.

In the current stable 0.3 /config/env/all file has an assets section for required css/js with public/lib/angular public/lib/bootstrap.

From there Angular dependency injection is done in /public/config.js. And then require it in any controllers you might need.

Note  /config/env/all is config/assets/default in meanjs 0.4